# which is the more accurate way of calculating mean?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, means

I have two formulas of calculating a mean Direct and shortcut I guess, which one is accurate(Accuracy and precision ) and dont have errors, how to prove it ?

$$ \overline{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^r \tilde{x}_i f_i
\qquad \overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} $$
EDIT:

- $\tilde{x}_i$ =  midpoint of the ith interval,
- $f_i$ =  frequency  of  ith interval,
- $r$ =   number  of  intervals

Comment: Please explain your variables $r, f_i, \tilde{x}_i$ etc.

Comment: If $f_i$ is meant to be the frequency with which $x_i$ occurs then the second formula is the same as the first in the case when each $x_i$ occurs with frequency $1$.

Comment: @gammatester,I have Edited, I know they could have the same results but sometimes one of them is more accurate, do you think that its the second one?

Comment: @lulu what do you think?

Comment: I fixed your formatting. (you may wish to verify I haven't introduced any errors)

Comment: It depends on the numbers. From your formulation I guess you are interested in actual numerical computation. The first is IMO more accurate if you have very different $x_i$. Assume you have $1000$ double precision numbers $x_1=2, x_2=x_3=\dots x_{1000} = 10^{-16}$. The the first mean is $0.0020000000000001000$ the second $0.002$, while the true value is $0.0020000000000000999$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of numbers you are dealing with. The second formula will work always with any set of numbers. It could be good for distributions of numbers that are somewhat uniform, i.e. that no number exists in much greater quantities than the others. The second one should be used when the distribution deviates from the uniform distribution. It is good for calculating the mean of nearly continuous distributions (such as those that are run discretely over many trials). Taking the limit of the first expression yields $$\int x\cdot f(x) dx,$$ which is the expression for calculating the mean of a continuous distribution.

So in summary: the second one will work for discrete distributions only. The second one always works, though you need not consider frequencies in simple scenarios (such as when you need to calculate the mean of 3 numbers) and thus it may not be practical.

Comment: so the second one is the best one, how can I prove it with examples or graph

Comment: @Sultan Well if you are working with distributions, you can say for nearly continuous distributions, it is easier to sum the product of the value and the frequency than to count each item individually.

Comment: what about discrete

Comment: @Sultan If you are given a list of raw data (like just a list of numbers), it might be marginally easier to use the second formula because you don't have to count frequencies. If you are given a value-frequency table, the first method should be marginally easier. They both give the same answers for discrete distributions, and only when you come to continuous distributions does one prevail over the other (because the second expression fails).